# Sort date in format "date +%a %b %d %T %Y"

Tags: date, sort

I want to Sort the data in a file considering the date column (last column in the sample data). I have tried some commands but didn't get succeeded.

Sample data:

```
Beendet|48149|1550804401|STR|Fri Feb 22  4:00:45 2019
Beendet|940001|1550790961|CBST|Fri Feb 22  0:16:12 2019
Beendet|658521|1550817001|CANS|Fri Feb 22  7:30:10 2019
Beendet|48150|1550775601|EXP|Thu Feb 21 20:00:12 2019
Beendet|7|1550779201|MAS|Thu Feb 21 21:00:23 2019
Beendet|9072|1550777401|AMS0|Thu Feb 21 20:52:17 2019
Beendet|9220|1550804401|AMS1|Fri Feb 22  4:00:09 2019
Beendet|670|1550811601|MOR|Fri Feb 22  6:00:07 2019
Beendet|73|1550790061|HIST|Fri Feb 22  2:00:30 2019
Beendet|122|1550804821|HIST1|Fri Feb 22  4:07:08 2019
```

These are my tries:

```
sort -r -k5.12 -k5.9 completefile.txt (sorting using the date and time field lengths)
sort -n -k5,5 completefile.txt 
sort -k5n,5 completefile.txt
```

All are giving the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Awk script: convert the last field to timestamp and compare.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS = "|"
}

{
    data[NR] = $0
    cmd = "date \"+%s\" --date " "\"" $5 "\""
    cmd|getline
    stamp2idx[$0] = NR
}

END {
    asorti(stamp2idx, sorted)
    for (n in sorted) {
        print data[stamp2idx[sorted[n]]]
    }
}
```

**output**

```
➤ ./solution.awk data                                                       20:39:09
Beendet|48150|1550775601|EXP|Thu Feb 21 20:00:12 2019
Beendet|9072|1550777401|AMS0|Thu Feb 21 20:52:17 2019
Beendet|7|1550779201|MAS|Thu Feb 21 21:00:23 2019
Beendet|940001|1550790961|CBST|Fri Feb 22  0:16:12 2019
Beendet|73|1550790061|HIST|Fri Feb 22  2:00:30 2019
Beendet|9220|1550804401|AMS1|Fri Feb 22  4:00:09 2019
Beendet|48149|1550804401|STR|Fri Feb 22  4:00:45 2019
Beendet|122|1550804821|HIST1|Fri Feb 22  4:07:08 2019
Beendet|670|1550811601|MOR|Fri Feb 22  6:00:07 2019
Beendet|658521|1550817001|CANS|Fri Feb 22  7:30:10 2019
```

Comment: Thank you...I will test this script in my environment.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly to get
the intended order, you should specify the sort criteria for each field:

```
sort -k5n -k2M -k3n -k4V file.txt
```

Where

- `-k5n` col 5 (year) in numerical order
- `-k2M` col 2 in "month" order
- `-k3n` col 3 (day) in numerical order
- `-k4V` col 4 (time) in "Version" order

If you can change the log process, consider using `date -Is` (2019-02-22T12:20:28+00:00), and sorting with

```
sort -t '|' -k5   file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try and provide you an update.

Comment: One thing I have tried is : consider the command: `cut -f5 -d '|' completefile.txt | sort -r -k1.8,1.18` which sorts perfectly only if I consider the date column. How I can use this in the sample file for the sorting the whole data?

Comment: I have simplified the command and got the expected result:  `sort -t '|' -r -k5.8,5.18 -n -k3 completefile.txt`   1. Applied length wise sort on 5th column and 2. number sort on 3rd column. (Temporary solution).

Comment: @Ravi, why not just `sort -t '|' -k5  ` ?

Comment: it didn't sorted properly with the `sort -t '|' -k5` command, I thought it is due to the field is looks like a string contains both char and numeric values.

Comment: @Ravi, what was rong?

Answer (score 0):

I have simplified the command and got the expected result:

```
sort -t '|' -r -k5.8,5.18 -n -k3 completefile.txt
```

1. Applied length wise sort on 5th column and
2. number sort on 3rd column.